# Magento 2 REST API, get attribute values instead of ids

Tags: magento2, rest-api

When I make a REST call to get product data, any multi-select attribute (in custom_attributes) is return with a numeric id rather than its text value, ie:

```
24 => {#2105
  +"attribute_code": "manufacturer"
  +"value": "574"
}
25 => {#2106
  +"attribute_code": "barcode"
  +"value": "XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
}
26 => {#2107
  +"attribute_code": "color"
  +"value": "466"
}
27 => {#2108
  +"attribute_code": "gender"
  +"value": "134"
}
28 => {#2109
  +"attribute_code": "shipping_type"
  +"value": "793"
}
29 => {#2110
  +"attribute_code": "top_size"
  +"value": "215"
```

How can I return the value of these attributes instead of just the id?